Linux Reserved memory through DMA API
I been fighting with this issue for some days now. I need to reserve and allocate 2 MB of RAM to my device driver.
I followed the this guide from Xilinx [https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841683/Linux+Reserved+Memory][1].
my Device tree looks like this
reserved-memory {
#address-cells = <2>;
#size-cells = <2>;
ranges;
      reserved: buffer@0x60000000 {
      compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
      no-map;      
      reg = <0x0 0x60000000 0x0 0x00400000>;   
      };
};
my_driver@0 {
  compatible = "dummy,my_driver";
  status = "okay";
  memory-region = <&reserved>;
};

and my Probing funtion in the "my_driver"
static int my_driver_probe(struct platform_device *pdev){
  ...
  rc = of_reserved_mem_device_init(&pdev->dev);
  debug = dma_set_coherent_mask(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(32));
  v_addr = dma_alloc_coherent(&pdev->dev, MY_MEM_SIZE, &paddr, GFP_KERNEL);
        
  printk("Allocated coherent memory Size: %d MB, vaddr: 0x%0llX paddr: 0x%0llX\n",\
             ( MY_MEM_SIZE / 1024 / 1024 ), (u64)v_addr, (u32)paddr);   
  ...

Kernel boot log:
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x60000000, size 2 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node buffer@0x60000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool

Before inserting a new module I write some data to the physical RAM mem region
$devmem 0x60000000 0x12345678
my_driver log output
[  415.244373] [ my_driver ] Device Tree Probing
[  415.248912] my_driver my_driver@0: assigned reserved memory node buffer@0x60000000
[  415.262226] [ my_driver ] Mask set.
[  415.266104] [ my_driver ] Memory allocated.
[  415.266107] [ my_driver ] Allocated coherent memory Size: 2 MB, vaddr: 0xFFFF80000A600000 paddr: 0x60000000
[  415.280364] [ my_driver ]Reading virt_addr 0xFFFF80000A600000  0x0 

After inserting the driver
root@demo:~# devmem 0x60000000 
0x00000000

So I see two problems: my memory is being cleared after allocation and the virtual memory is not readable/writable.
Any ideas what I might be missing ?
I would be tremendously grateful if someone could share some wisdom ;-)

Note that buffer@0x60000000 is slightly obsolete syntax. It shouldn't have the 0x prefix.

dma_alloc_coherent does clear the allocated memory. This is for security reasons. You have not shown the code that reads/writes from/to the virtual address, so I cannot comment on that. I assume you can read back the written value with the devmem command before inserting the driver (i.e. before dma_alloc_coherent zeroes it)?

If you write a non-zero value to the memory from the driver (after the dma_alloc_coherent call), can you read it with devmem?

Hi @IanAbbott many thanks for your prompt reply.
for reading the memory
read_result = (volatile uint64_t)(v_addr);
printk("Reading virt_addr 0x%0llX  0x%0llX \n", (v_addr ), (volatile uint64_t)v_addr );

What would be the best way to test the assigned virtual address ?
Devmem does not work.

Yes I read before inserting ..if dma_alloc_coherent zeroes it than it makes sense that it reads all zeros.

The driver can write a special value to the virtual address, and the user can use devmem to read back the special value from the corresponding physical address.

Hi @IanAbbott I can now read and write!
Is it possible to disable the clear memory "feature" on dma_alloc_coherent?

Your driver has a pointer (virtual address) to the DMA coherent memory so it can read and write the memory. Disabling the clearing of memory by dma_alloc_coherent is a bad idea.

Ok I see. Many thanks for your help. I believe the question is answered and problem solved.
I just need now to add a few more reserved memory ranges for my driver. I will open another OP.

Hi @IanAbbott
do you know how to reserve multiple memory ranges ?
I created a new post here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79244421/how-to-allocate-multiple-reserved-memories-through-dma-api
