How to allocate multiple reserved memories through DMA API
I need to reserve around 3 or 4 memory regions that are used by a single device driver.
I followed the guide from Xilinx. which works for a single memory region.
The Device tree looks like this:
reserved-memory {
#address-cells = <2>;
#size-cells = <2>;
ranges;
      reserved_m1: buffer1@60000000 {
      compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
      no-map;      
      reg = <0x0 0x60000000 0x0 0x00400000>;   
      };
      reserved_m2: buffer2@80000000 {
      compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
      no-map;      
      reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x00100000>;   
      };
};
my_driver@0 {
  compatible = "dummy,my_driver";
  status = "okay";
  memory-region = <&reserved_m1>, <&reserved_m2>;
};

and my Probing function in the "my_driver"
static int my_driver_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
  ...
  rc = of_reserved_mem_device_init(&pdev->dev);
  debug = dma_set_coherent_mask(&pdev->dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(32));
  v_addr_m1 = dma_alloc_coherent(&pdev->dev, MY_MEM1_SIZE, &paddr, GFP_KERNEL); 
  printk("Allocated coherent memory Size: %d MB, vaddr: 0x%0llX paddr: 0x%0llX\n", MY_MEM_SIZE / 1024 / 1024, (u64)v_addr, (u32)paddr);

  rc = of_reserved_mem_device_init_by_idx(&pdev->dev, np, 1);
  v_addr_m2 = dma_alloc_coherent(&pdev->dev, MY_MEM2_SIZE, &paddr_m2, GFP_KERNEL);
    
  printk("Allocated coherent memory Size: %d MB, vaddr: 0x%0llX paddr: 0x%0llX\n", MY_MEM_SIZE / 1024 / 1024, (u64)v_addr, (u32)paddr);
  ...
  ...

With the above probing method I can only allocate for the first reserved-memory region.
How do I properly allocate for each regions?

Are they all used to allocate DMA coherent memory?

yes, they are DMA coherent

According to the function header comment on of_reserved_mem_device_init_by_idx(), when the driver needs to use more than one reserved memory region, it should allocate child devices (at runtime, not in the devicetree) and initialize regions for the child devices. It should be possible to use one of the memory regions in the parent, and create a child device for each of the remaining memory regions. The only reasonable-looking example I can find is "drivers/media/platform/samsung/s5p-mfc/s5p_mfc.c" which deserves some careful study.

many thanks for your prompt reply. This is indeed a much more complex solution than I was expecting. I had to read the code 5x to understand ;-)
I need to allocate 1MB( that is already pcie device virtual memory) for the extra reserved memory.  I only need to read and write some "bits" ...dma is not necessarily a must. Just I  thought I could use the API for multiple DMA regions without much headache. I would like to have a method to specify the second reserved memory as for the first. I am tremendously thankful for your guidance.

perhaps this is a dummy questions but you think it should be possible to have a shared-dma-pool and non?
reserved-  memory {
#address-cells = <2>;
#size-cells = <2>;
ranges;
  reserved_m0: buffer@0 {
     compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
     no-map;
     reg = <0x0 0x70000000 0x0 0x10000000>;
  };
  reserved_m1: buffer@1 {
     no-map;
     reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x10000000>;
  };

};
reserved-driver@0 {
compatible = "xlnx,reserved-memory";
memory-region = <&reserved_m0>, <&reserved_m1>,;
};
